# How to use the jquery's .on() method when the elements are created dynamically through ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mostrar_usuario_link').on('click', function() {
        $("#mostrar_usuario_dialog").dialog({
            modal:false
        }) 
    });
})
```

The elements that are part of that class (.mostrar_usuario_link) aren't there when the document is ready because those are dynamically created via ajax only when it's requested. Anyway, the dialog is never shown and i was wondering if it's because of that.

By the way, the set of elements in the .mostrar_usuario_link class are < a > tags and i'm using DOJO for Ajax support.

Can i get any help with this?

Comment: Believe it or not, this *actually covered* in the documentation... it's called "delegated" events and supersedes `delegate` (which superseded `live`).

Comment: I would recommend looking at jQuery's ajax support: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve my problem. Since i was using the anchor tag of Dojo (< sx:a >), it was executing only its own script. However, you can use the "afterNotifyTopics" attribute to indicate a script you want to execute after the response.

Here is the HTML:

```
<s:url id="mostrar_usuario_url" action="mostrar_usuario.action">
    <s:param name="id_usuario" value="%{id_usuario}"/>
</s:url>
<sx:a cssClass="mostrar_usuario_link" id="mostrar_usuario_link_%{id_usuario}" targets="mostrar_usuario_dialog" href="%{mostrar_usuario_url}" afterNotifyTopics="lanzarCuadro">
    <s:property value="id_usuario"/>
</sx:a>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    dojo.event.topic.subscribe("lanzarCuadro", function() {
        $("#mostrar_usuario_dialog").dialog({
            modal:true
        })
    });
}
```

Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct usage:

```
$("body").on("click", ".mostrar_usuario_link", function() {
    ...
});
```

Instead of `body` you can use any parent element of `mostrar_usuario_link`.

Reference:

- [jQuery docs > on() > delegated-events approach](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: +1 *just because* of mentioning that `body` can be "any parent element of...". Using a parent closer to the intended targets will result in a slightly more (possibly unnoticeably so) efficient execution but, more importantly, IMOHO, gives a better defined scope to the event.

Comment: I appreciate the help but that doesn't seem to work. I should have mentioned that the set of elements are < a > tags since i tried your method with any other element and it worked.

Comment: @DanielCalderonMori That is strange. In fact, there is no difference in what kind of elements is clicked, this method should work perfectly with any clickable elements.

Comment: I know. I gave the id "test" to a < td > element inside the parent element and your method worked perfectly. By the way i'm using < sx:a > from Dojo for Ajax support but in the client-side it is just an < a > element so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Could the issue be that you aren't using preventDefault on the `<a>` element? Please see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905104/how-to-use-the-jquerys-on-method-when-the-elements-are-created-dynamically-t/10905144#10905144 . Otherwise posting a fiddle could help.

Comment: Thank you, but i already solve my problem. The problem was that, since  i was using the anchor tags provided by DOJO (< sx:a >), it runs its own javascript so it didn't obey mine. Anyway, i used de afterTopics attribute and assign a script to run after the response.

Answer (score 1):

> The document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.

http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

```
$("document").on("click", ".mostrar_usuario_link", function() {
    ...
});
```

Also I'm not sure if you are doing this already, but if the element is an `<a>` tag, you might want to [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to prevent the anchor tag's default action.

```
$("document").on("click", ".mostrar_usuario_link", function(e) {
    //Prevent Default action from link
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with AJAX you have to *reassign* the events once the HTML you where asking for (asynchronously) is ready. How to do so? Take a look:

```
   $.ajax({
      url: '....',
      success: someFunction
   });
```

Now, you probably already have the code for *someFunction*, which is:

```
function someFunction(){
  $('.mostrar_usuario_link').on('click', function() {
      $("#mostrar_usuario_dialog").dialog({
          modal:false
      }) 
  });
}
```

You can have the new HTML in the *success*, as you probably already know, through the *data* parameter. For further reference take a look to the [jQuery's .ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).